# Unable to infer the types for templated ufcs functions

Tags: d

```
struct None{};
struct Some(T){
  T value;
}
Optional!T some(T)(T value){
  return Optional!T(Some!T(value));
}
bool isNone(T)(ref Optional!T optional){
  return optional.peek!None != null;
}
bool isSome(T)(ref Optional!T optional){
  return optional.peek!(Some!T) != null;
}
Optional!T none(T)(){
  return Optional!T(None());
}
alias Optional(T) = std.variant.Algebraic!(Some!(T),None);
void main()
{
  Optional!int si = none!int();
  writeln(isNone!int(si));
  writeln(isSome(si)); //cannot deduce function from argument types
}
```

Why do I have to call `isSome` and `isNone` with explicit types? Shouldn't D be able to infer the types?

I guess this happens because `Optional(T)` is only a type alias?

Comment: You are asking it to infer just part of the type... though the alias does seem to be confusing things. I'm not sure the compiler can take off that many layers of templates. Not just the alias, but Algebriac!(Some!T) has the T hidden kinda far inside too. But I think it should be able to...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Yeah I have wrapped it in a new type and it works now.

Comment: The problem is not the `alias` in this case. If you replace the `Optional!T` with it's aliased definition, it tells you that "T is undefined", even here:
`bool isSome(T)(ref std.variant.VariantN!(4UL, T, None) optional) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a DMD bug, the same pointed in this [NG thread](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/yhzadvyxijdyyoreatey@forum.dlang.org).

Once one aliases a template, template parameter deduction fails.

Comment: Maybe not a bug. I don't know the answer to this question but OP's code still can't infer the type arguments today with DMD.